How to download a PDF file in flutter using DIO
I want to download a PDF file and display it on screen. I have wrote a below code to achieve it but it gives me error. I tried many different things but got unsuccessful.
Error:
E/flutter (14805): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]
E/flutter (14805): Source stack:
E/flutter (14805): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
E/flutter (14805): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
E/flutter (14805): #2      DioForNative.download (package:dio/src/entry/dio_for_native.dart:84:24)
E/flutter (14805): #3      OpenBalanceController.getOpenBalancePDF (package:otrack/views/reports/controllers/open_balance_controller.dart:143:26)
E/flutter (14805): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14805): 
E/flutter (14805): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:643:7)
E/flutter (14805): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter (14805): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter (14805): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter (14805): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter (14805): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter (14805): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter (14805): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5)
E/flutter (14805): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617:45)
E/flutter (14805): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1665:54)
E/flutter (14805): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter (14805): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
E/flutter (14805): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
E/flutter (14805): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
E/flutter (14805): #14     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:7)
E/flutter (14805): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (14805): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

My DIO Api code:
  Future getOpenBalancePDF() async {
    isLoading.value = true;

    final headers = await BaseClient.generateHeaders();
    Dio dioWithHeaders = Dio(BaseOptions(
        receiveTimeout: 999999, sendTimeout: 999999, headers: headers));
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = "${dir.path}/TransactionSummary.pdf";
    final data = FormData.fromMap({
      "orderType": 0,
      "fromDate": "2000-01-01",
      "toDate": "2023-12-01",
      "customerFilterList": [1387, 1460],
      "exportFormat": 1,
      "openBalance": true
    });
    await dioWithHeaders.download(
      ApiConstants.POST_CUSTOMER_OPEN_BALANCE_REPORT,
      data: data,
      (Headers headers) {
        headers.map.values;
        return path;
      },
    );

    if (path.isNotEmpty) {
      Get.to(
        () => PDFScreen(
          path: path,
        ),
      );
    }
    isLoading.value = false;
  }

Edit: Postman screenshots are attached below with headers, body and response. As in screenshot API is working fine.
Postman Screenshots:



400 means your request is malformed or not understood in some way. Return to the API documentation to confirm what the request body should be. Try it in Postman - and if successful there, update the question with the successful request (headers and body).

@RichardHeap Please take a look I have added screenshots of postman

In Postman, you are sending a JSON body with type application/json. In dio you are sending multipart form data. These are completely different. In dio, try sending json.encode({'orderType': 0,...}) and set the content type to application/json.

You could place the call to await dioWithHeaders.download into a try block, catch the DioError and handle it.
As a side note: In Dart, Exceptions should normally be caught and handled, whereas Errors should lead to the termination of the program.  DioError was deprecated in favour of DioException starting with version 5.2.0, and it seems you are using an old version of Dio.
try {
  await dioWithHeaders.download(...);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // Handle error here: Http status error [400]. 
   
}

Also, instead of Future (which is in fact Future<dynamic>), the function getOpenBalancePDF should return Future<void>.

How can only this API show network error when all other API working fine? Is that because of running on emulator device?

Does the response and the message of the caught DioError include any more details? Regarding the emulator device consider posting a separate question.

There is only one error which is mentioned above, Are you sure it is a network error?

From the first line of your error post:  [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400].

That's not really a "network error". Http status 400 tells you the request is received but not understood.

On https://www.w3.org/TR/network-error-logging/#predefined-network-error-types they list three predefined network error types related to dns resolution, secure connection establishment, and transmission of request and response.   The error mentioned in the question body if of the latter type: http.error - The user agent successfully received a response, but it had a 4xx or 5xx status code.
